# PHP- PHP Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function SignupContr::signupUser()

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP php and took some lessons and now Im trying to practice, I used login with discord method and If user Is logged in the system sould add the discord id to database if user is not already in database but Im facing quite the issue and I have no luck so far to fix It myself, I even asked few of my buddies If they can see the issue but they did not also know the real issue.

My error:

```
[22-Jul-2022 06:56:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function 
SignupContr::signupUser(), 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\OOP-Test\inc\signup.inc.php on line 13 
and exactly 1 expected in C:\wamp64\www\OOP-Test\classes\signup-contr.class.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\OOP-Test\inc\signup.inc.php(13): SignupContr->signupUser()
#1 C:\wamp64\www\OOP-Test\dashboard\index.php(12): include('C:\\wamp64\\www\\O...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\wamp64\www\OOP-Test\classes\signup-contr.class.php on line 10
```

My code looks like this right now:

*signup.inc.php*

```
{
    $discord = $_GET['user'];

    include "../classes/dbh.class.php";
    include "../classes/signup.class.php";
    include "../classes/signup-contr.class.php";

    $signup = new SignupContr($discord);
 
    $signup->signupUser();

    //header('location: ../dashboard/index.php');
}
```

*signup.class.php*

```
class Signup extends Dbh {

    protected function setUser($discord){

        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` ('discord') VALUES (?);");
        if(!$stmt->execute(array($discord))) {
         //  $stmt = null;
           // header("location: ../dashboard/index.php?useraddfailed");
          //  exit();
        }
        $stmt->debugDumpParams();
        $stmt = null;
    }

}
```

*signup-contr.class.php*

```
class SignupContr extends Signup{

    private $discord;
    public function _construct($discord){
        $this->discord = $discord;
    }

    public function signupUser(){
        $this->setUser($this->discord);
        var_dump($this->discord);
    }
}
```

I have not done the check part If user Is allready In the database

Comment: What library / SDK are you actually using there?

Answer (score 0):

I Finally found the issue. I was missing one underscore in construct.

*signup.contr.class.php* should be like this:

```
class SignupContr extends Signup{

    private $discord;
    public function __construct($discord){
        $this->discord = $discord;
    }

    public function signupUser(){
        $this->setUser($this->discord);
        var_dump($this->discord);
    }
}
```

Of course it was the simplest issue there Is but I really tought there suppost to be only one underscore. You always should check the simple things first, I did not because usally you don't use construct In procedural php